# Regex to extract function from c++ function calls

Tags: c++, regex

I have to extract a function name from various c++ function calls. Following are some of the function calls examples and extracted function names highlighted.

- `std::basic_fstream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::~basic_fstream<char,std::char_traits<char> >`
  ~basic_fstream
- `CSocket::Send` send
- `CMap<unsigned int,unsigned int &,tagLAUNCHOBJECT,tagLAUNCHOBJECT &>::RemoveAll
  Cerner::Foundations::String::Rep::~Rep`~Rep
- `CCMessage::~CCMessage` ~CCMessage
- `std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >,u`_Tree
- `Lib::DispatcherCache::~DispatcherCache`~DispatcherCache
- `CPrefDataObjectLoader<CPrefManagerKey,CPrefManagerValue,CGetPrefManager,PrefManagerKeyFunctor>::Get` Get

  The following Regex works for most of the functions
- `/((?:[^:]*))$';/` This regex get the string from the last :
- `/+?(?=<)';/` This one removes string that starts with <

But for `std::basic_fstream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::~basic_fstream<char,std::char_traits<char> >`  the output I get is `char_traits` because this string is after last ':' but the result should be `~basic_fstream`. Is there a way I can combine both regex and ignore everything that is within `<>`?

Comment: take your pick of online tools to help you get there:
https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=online%20regex%20builder

Comment: @KenWite looks like that one asking to parse out function name from the source code. Here my question is more complex. I need to parse out function name from the different function calls.

Answer (score 3):

The grammar of C++ is not only not regular, it's actually highly context-sensitive (especially near templates). Even a proper CFG parser won't help you, let alone a plain old regex… Rather than trying to approximate the impossible using ugly and fragile hacks, why not use an actual tool for the job? If you want to parse C++, then use a C++ parser, such as [libclang](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/group__CINDEX.html).

Comment: I think there is no easy way. I don't want to use a parser for this as it is a simple project with a complex issue, though. The regex I use gives me 90% accurate results. I think I'll be fine with that.